# Substr in mongodb conditional aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to count the employees with valid mail id suffix with '@test.com'. I tried below queries,

```
db.emp.aggregate([
        { $match: {} },
        { $addFields:{
          "validEmail":{$cond:[{$eq:[{"$substr":["$emp_email",9,-1]},"@test.com"]},1,0]} 
           }
        }
    ])
```

Here, the $substr operator is not returning the output in reverse way. My assumption is that -1 on the 3rd argument should substr with reverse way. It is not working.

I am using mongodb version lesser than 4.2 and not able to use $regexMatch. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: try using
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/

Answer (score 1):

You can `$split` using `@` and check whether the last index contains `test.com`.

```
  .aggregate([
    {
      "$project": {
        "validEmail": {
          "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [{ "$split": ["$emp_email", "@"] }, -1] },
            "test.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l8jbez4iibY)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use regex :

```
db.collection.find({
  email: {
    $regex: ".+@test.com\\b",
  }
})
```